# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el texto que escribo en un input en HTML cambie los caracteres por puntos?

Tags: html

No añadí codigo porque es algo simple, es solo un parafo pidiendo una contraseña y un input, nada de otro mundo.

*edit:*
¿Como puedo hacer que el contenido de una etiqueta `input` muestre puntos (como los de contraseña) en vez del texto que se escribe? Ademas de agregar una opción para mostrar el texto.

Por ejemplo si se escribe `"Sanko Pan"` cada caracter sea cambiado por un `"*"` quedando `"*********"`

Comment: mencionas un código pero ¿dónde esta?

Comment: Solo es el input con el nombre, por lo que veo no sale, lo agregue pero cuando subo la pregunta no aparece, perdón pero empecé a usar esto hace 10 minutos

Comment: No hay problema, intenta pegar el codigo, seleccionalo todo y luego le das al boton con el simbolo de "{ }" que sirve para llevarlo a formato de codigo

Comment: Te recomiendo visitar esta página https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_type_password.asp

Answer (score 2):

Tal como menciona @denso para que un `<input>` muestre su contenido como si se tratara de una contraseña le pones un `type="password"` quedando: `<input type="password>`, esto resuelve la primera parte del problema.

Sobre una opción para mostrar el texto, pues tendras que recurrir a *javascript* para alterar el valor de `type`, por ejemplo:

```
<div>
Contraseña: <input type="password" id="inputPasswd">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="showPasswd()">Mostrar contraseña
</div>
<script>
const showPasswd =() => {
  let passwd = document.getElementById("inputPasswd");
  if (passwd.type === "password") {
    passwd.type = "text";
  } else {
    passwd.type = "password";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias bro! Es de mucha ayuda tu ayuda jajajaja

Comment: No hay problema, si esto soluciono tu problema marca la respuesta como la correcta para que el post no vuelva a salir en el feed de la pagina

Comment: Gracias por el tip, voy a hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password

Los elementos  de tipo "password" proporcionan una forma para que el usuario ingrese una contraseña de forma segura. El elemento se presenta como un control de editor de texto, sin formato, de una línea, en el que el texto está oculto para que no pueda leerse, generalmente reemplazando cada carácter con un símbolo como el asterisco ("*") o un punto ("•"). Este carácter variará dependiendo del user agent (en-US) y del OS.

Comment: Thanks bro!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para ocultar y mostrar contraseña en un input:

```
function mostrar(){
  var tipo = document.getElementById("password");
  if(tipo.type == "password"){
      tipo.type = "text";
  }else{
      tipo.type = "password";
  }
}
  
<input class="contraseña" type="password" name="password" id="password">

<button onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar Contraseña</button>
```